# Can't open connection when shortcut-knitting in RStudio

Tags: r, connection, rstudio, knitr

I have a CSV file I made shared publicly via Google Drive. I used bit.ly to generate a nice short URL, and I can read it into R just fine via

```
read.csv("http://bit.ly/1pRClOk")
```

(It's a pretty small dataframe, 9x17, so don't be worried about trying it out.)
I put my code in in a .Rmd document, and I can `knit` it just fine from the console if I run `knit("csvtest.Rmd")`, but if I knit using the `Knit HTML` button in RStudio (Ctrl-Shift-K), I get

> Error in `file(file, "rt")`: Cannot open the connection.

In general, I much prefer to knit using the shortcut, because doing so seems to knit in it's own R session which means I can be sure I'm not accidentally referencing something in my global environment. I'd also like to distribute the .Rmd file without having to explain to people that they need to explicitly `knit` from the console.

**Is there a way I can make make the connection work when using the `knit` shortcuts?**

I'm on Windows 7 and using current versions of RStudio (0.98.1091) and knitr (1.8).

#### MWE

Using this document saved as `csvtest.Rmd`. I can run the code in RStudio line by line, no problem, typing `knit2html("csvtest.Rmd")` produces an HTML document with the data. Knitting via shortcut produces the error above.

````
---
title: "Can knitr open connections?"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
reentry = read.csv("http://bit.ly/1pRClOk")
head(reentry)
```
````

Comment: FWIW, I get the same error message just copy and pasting your `read.csv("http://bit.ly/1pRClOk")` into my R for Windows GUI... Could you please provide a minimal example of the knitr source document that's giving you the variable behavior?

Comment: Hmmm, so do I. No problem in RStudio, doesn't work in RGui. Both programs are checked to be "allowed" through the Windows firewall.

Comment: And I also get the same error message when I paste directly into Rstudio. Are you sure the document knits correctly from the RStudio command line even when run from a completely fresh session (in which you've done `rm(list=ls(all=T))` to remove everything from the global environment)?

Comment: Just restarted R and verified: yes it does.

Comment: And it works for me too. Interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only care about a solution under Windows, I believe you need to `setInternet2(TRUE)` in te Rmd file before you read the file, since it is essentially an HTTPS link, which you cannot read into R by default.

A more portable solution is to use the [downloader](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/downloader/) package to download the file (you can download it to a `tempfile()`) before reading it.

Comment: Nice, that fixes it for me.

Comment: Thanks! The `downloader` package is exactly what I want, and the `setInternet2` is nice to know about. Never would have found it on my own.